# be excited + infinitive

Tags: phrase-request, to-infinitive, infinitive-phrases

I understand that "I'm excited to see her" means that I am looking forward to seeing her.
The sentence seems for me to have a similar structure with such senteces:
1. I'm surprised to see her.
2. I'm happy to see her.
But when you say the sentences number 1 and 2, you have already seen her, while you haven't seen her when you say "I'm excited to see her."
I would like to know other examples of infinitives where their meaning is similar with "to see" in "I'm excited to see her," if there are any.

Comment: I would say "I'm excited about seeing her" if I hadn't seen her yet.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you very much for your help!  I understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that immediately comes to mind is "keen to see her".  There are probably other variants of words with similar meanings.  You can also for similar senses with participles: "I'm hoping to meet her".